# keras conv2d layers does not include second channel into training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have two sets of images for input data, which has a shape (32000, 256, 256, 2).

I set batch_size=128

> model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3),
>                           padding='same',
>                           input_shape=(256, 256, 2) ))

The Conv2D layer should take both two channels into training. However, I found the second channel is not included in the training. Because when I flip over the order of first and second channels, it gives totally different result.

Is there anything I did incorrect? I will appreciate if you would help me!

Comment: Your assumption that changing the channels should keep results the same is completely incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Could you please explain it in more details?